# eclipse java annotation processing commit generated java classes with subclipse to svn

Tags: java, annotations, commit, subversive, annotation-processing

I'm using Java annotation processing to generate a couple of Java source files. I enabled it on the project specific settings (*Properties -> Java Compile -> Annotation Processing*). The generation works fine and the classes end up in the `.apt_generated` source folder.

Unfortunately, I'm not able to commit the generated Java source files with *Subversive* to the svn server. If I selected the `.apt_generated` source folder and perform *Team -> Add to Version Control ...* the dialog doesn't list any files to commit. So far, I have been committing `.apt_generated` source folder from the command line. Can I customize this behavior? I wasn't able to find anything on this in the team preferences.

I'm aware of the option adjusting the headless build. Since my files won't be changed to often, I just would like to commit the generated files for the moment. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this behaviour can be found in [this](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/163903/) thread: Subversive doesn't allow to commit "derived" resources. The folder used by the annotation processing and all contained resources automatically get the "derived" flag, which you can verify on their Properties->Resource page.

I'm in a similar situation as you wanting to commit generated files at least initially. There is a plugin that apparently makes it possible to override the behaviour of setting the "derived" flag, which I'm going to test now: [AutoDeriv](http://nodj.github.io/AutoDeriv/)

Comment: I'm using GIT in the current project, so don't face the issue any more. Thank you, me telling the reason why the files were irgnored!

Answer (score 0):

Since this has been unanswered for over a year, I'll take a stab at it.  I had a similar problem with Eclipse's .project and .classpath files, which I wanted maintained in Subversion.

I believe you may have to tell Eclipse not to ignore "resources."  These are files that have extensions but no names (e.g. .project or .classpath or .apt_generated).  From Eclipse's Project Explorer click on the View Menu icon (the upside down triangle icon).  Then Customize View... then remove the check from the checkbox labeled .* resources.